# table rows not aligned

Tags: tables

The alignment of my table is all out of whack. Can you help?

Additionally, the commas and periods are not what I expect them to be.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{#1}} 
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\author{}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\small
\caption{Comparing goodness of fit tests
for different specifications of pay-performance equation.} \label{tab:table}

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}
   l S[table-format=4.2] S[table-format=5.2]
   *{2}{S[table-format=6.2]} @{}}
\toprule
& \mC{eq. 1} & \mC{eq. 2} & \mC{eq. 3} \\
\midrule
R-sqaure    & {.255} & {.072} & {.231} \\
\addlinespace
Adj. R-square   & 0.254   & .070   & .2299    \\ 
F-statistic & 140.94$^{*}$   & 37.26$^{*}$     & 357.81    \\
Sample Size    & 11,536    &  11,529   & 11,950     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\smallskip
$^{*}$ Significant at the 1\% level.
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks a bunch!

UPDATE FOR ZARKO:

When I copy and pasted your preamble in, I got an error. In a mad dash I quickly hit command-z to undo and tried copy and pasting your preamble in a separate section, then worked backwards, deleting the things that were duplicated. This seemed to have worked, but it would be cool if you could look at it and clean it up again if necessary. I'm not sure what the error was by the way.

My new preamble:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{#1}} 
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

%ZARKO:
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-integer-digits,% in case of rounding decimals to three digits can be omitted
         group-separator={,},
         group-minimum-digits=4
         }
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}
%END ZARKO

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\author{}

\begin{document}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: you require that groups are separated with comma ... if yiz like to have grouped only integer part of numbers, than use `\sisetup{group-integer-digits,
         group-separator={,}, 
         group-minimum-digits=4}`.

Comment: i don't know how important are decimals, but try to consider to round decimal part to two digits (with adding `round-mode=places, round-precision=2`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let me convert my comments to an answer :-)

- you require that groups are separated with comma ...
- if you like to have grouped only integer part of numbers, than in `\sisetup` use `group-integer-digits`
- in this case it is sensible to round decimal part of numbers, for example to three digits

of topic:

- in mwe below drop out all not relevant packages
- remained packages i grouped according to their functions (coding, fonts, tables, units, caption)

mwe:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-integer-digits,% in case of rounding decimals to three digits can be omitted
         group-separator={,},
         group-minimum-digits=4
         }
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\small
\caption{Comparing goodness of fit tests
for different specifications of pay-performance equation.} \label{tab:table}

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}
        l
   *{3}{S[table-format=3.3,
          table-space-text-post=*,
          round-mode=places,
          round-precision=3]} @{}}
\toprule
                & \mC{eq. 1}    & \mC{eq. 2}    & \mC{eq. 3} \\
\midrule
R-sqaure        & .255          &  .072         & .231      \\
\addlinespace[2pt]
Adj. R-square   & 0.254         & .070          & .2299     \\
F-statistic     & 140.94$^{*}$  & 37.26$^{*}$   & 357.81    \\
Sample Size     & {11,536}      & {11,529}      & {11,950}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\smallskip
$^{*}$ Significant at the 1\% level.
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**
my mwe also work with your complete preamble. in my test i reorganize it to

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wasysym}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{#1}}
%
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={,},
         group-minimum-digits=4
         }
%
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, 
                     labelfont=bf, 
                     singlelinecheck=no}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{footmisc}
```

seem if it is complete and if it works with your documents.

Comment: That looks much better. Thanks @Zarko! could you look at the update I made for a follow-up question? Thanks!